# linux bash find file name with several digits

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder containing files jobs_1, jobs_2 ... jobs_77. I used

```
find  . -name  "job_[0-9]{1,2}"  -type  f
```

to list these files, but got no output. What is the problem?

Comment: Globs are not regexs.

Comment: `man find` and search for `-regex`.

Answer (score 4):

Or, to be friendly:

```
find  . -regextype posix-awk -regex  ".*job_[0-9]{1,2}.*"  -type  f
```

Note: posix-extended for example will yield the same result in this case; but being inherently lazy I chose awk because it's shorter :}

Answer (score 1):

The first problem with the command in the question:

```
find .-name "job_[0-9]{1,2}" -type f
```

...is that you are searching for files that start with the string `jobs_` instead of `job_` so the above command will not find any of the files named files job**s**_1, job**s**_2 ... job**s**_77.

The correct command to use is:

```
find . -regextype posix-awk -regex ".*jobs_[0-9]{1,2}.*" -type f -exec basename {} \;
```

- `-regextype posix-awk` - This option changes the regular expression syntax understood by `-regex` which allows the `find` program to use `posix-awk` regular expressions.
- `-exec basename {} \;` - Converts the results of `find . -regextype posix-awk -regex ".*jobs_[0-9]{1,2}.*" -type f` from the full path of the files to the file names, so that only the file names are displayed in the results. This makes the results of `find -type f` with the `-regex` option similar to the results of `find -type f` without the `-regex` option in which only the file names are displayed.